# How to get specific repository info from github url in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, github, github-api

I want to get specific repository's information using curl.

Suppose my GitHub repo url is like:

https://github.com/githubexample/Example-Repository

Now, when I put this url in my input form and submit then as a result, it would show this repository's title and description.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you may be interested in this link.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get

Using curl you can send a GET request to

`GET /repos/:username/:repo`

This describes exactly what you are looking for.

example: `curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World`

This will return a json document including "name" and "description".

edit: Added better information and an example.